# SparkThriftServer crashed after 11 days

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, hortonworks-data-platform

Using Spark 2.3.0 (running on ec2 in standalone mode) with Hadoop 2.7.6 and aws sdk 1.7.4, sparksql queries parquet files living on S3. Queries have been running fine over the last week but all of a sudden STS crashed while small query was running, same small query on same data that has been running  before.

Does anyone know the cause of this error?

```
18/10/11 04:37:04 ERROR Utils: uncaught error in thread spark-listener-group-eventLog, stopping SparkContext
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.hugeCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:123)
            at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:117)
            at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
            at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFastOutputStream.write(S3AFastOutputStream.java:194)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.write(FSDataOutputStream.java:58)
            at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
            at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
            at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
            at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:282)
            at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
            at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:207)
            at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:129)
            at java.io.BufferedWriter.write(BufferedWriter.java:230)
            at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:456)
            at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:473)
            at java.io.PrintWriter.print(PrintWriter.java:603)
            at java.io.PrintWriter.println(PrintWriter.java:739)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener$$anonfun$logEvent$1.apply(EventLoggingListener.scala:143)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener$$anonfun$logEvent$1.apply(EventLoggingListener.scala:143)
            at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.logEvent(EventLoggingListener.scala:143)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.onTaskEnd(EventLoggingListener.scala:164)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListenerBus$class.doPostEvent(SparkListenerBus.scala:45)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue.doPostEvent(AsyncEventQueue.scala:37)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue.doPostEvent(AsyncEventQueue.scala:37)
            at org.apache.spark.util.ListenerBus$class.postToAll(ListenerBus.scala:82)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue.org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$super$postToAll(AsyncEventQueue.scala:89)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch$1.apply(AsyncEventQueue.scala:89)
            at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue.org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch(AsyncEventQueue.scala:83)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(AsyncEventQueue.scala:79)
            at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1265)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anon$1.run(AsyncEventQueue.scala:78)
18/10/11 04:37:04 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 28.0 in stage 13058.0 (TID 553499) in 252 ms on 10.13.5.60 (executor 0) (16/63)
18/10/11 04:37:04 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 23.0 in stage 13058.0 (TID 553494) in 253 ms on 10.13.5.60 (executor 0) (17/63)
18/10/11 04:37:04 ERROR Utils: throw uncaught fatal error in thread spark-listener-group-eventLog
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
18/10/11 04:37:04 INFO HiveServer2: Shutting down HiveServer2
18/10/11 04:37:04 INFO ThriftCLIService: Thrift server has stopped
18/10/11 04:37:04 INFO AbstractService: Service:ThriftBinaryCLIService is stopped.
18/10/11 04:37:04 INFO AbstractService: Service:OperationManager is stopped.
18/10/11 04:37:04 INFO AbstractService: Service:SessionManager is stopped.
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Make xmx heap memory huge like 64gb